# Android How to update Background color from PreferenceList directly

Tags: android, preferences

I have a ListPreference containing colors. Only when I restart the application that the colors are being changed, not directly. How do I make it change directly when I click ?

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
        sharedpreferences2 = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("Color");
        CharSequence entry = listPreference.getEntry();
        final String value = listPreference.getValue();
        final ListView rel = this.getListView();


        if (sharedpreferences2.contains("Color")) {


            if (value.toString().equals("Red")) {

                rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            }
            if (value.toString().equals("Blue")) {

                rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

            }
            if (value.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Green")) {

                rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need the [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html). Use `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` in your `onResume()` and override the  `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` method to perform actions on preference change.

Unregister the listener in your `onPause()` method.

P.S. `PreferenceActivity` is deprecated, consider using [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) instead.

Comment: Fixed it, I restarted the activity inside the listener. Thanks.